# Notification is not showing when data is changing from firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-notifications

```
public class ListenOrder extends Service {

    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    String UID;
    CollectionReference requests;

    public ListenOrder() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        UID = Objects.requireNonNull(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()).getPhoneNumber();
        firebaseFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        requests=firebaseFirestore.collection("Requests").document(UID).collection("RequestStatus");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        requests.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                assert queryDocumentSnapshots != null;
                for(DocumentChange documentChange: queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){
                    switch (documentChange.getType()) {
                        case ADDED:

                            break;
                        case MODIFIED:
                            String doc= documentChange.getDocument().getString("Status");
                            showNotification(doc);
                            break;
                        case REMOVED:

                            break;
                    }

                }
            }
        });
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void showNotification(String status) {
        int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,order_status_activity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setContentText("Order was updated status to "+ConvertCodeToStatus(status))
                .setContentTitle("Notification Actions")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_view, "VIEW", contentIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,builder.build());
    }

    private String ConvertCodeToStatus(String status) {
        switch (status) {
            case "0":
                return "Placed";
            case "1":
                return "Processed";
            case "2":
                return "Dispatched";
            default:
                return "Delivered";
        }

    }

}
```

When I signing out the app the app is crashing and showing this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.getDocumentChanges()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.businessplan1.ListenOrder$1.onEvent(ListenOrder.java:81)
        at com.example.businessplan1.ListenOrder$1.onEvent(ListenOrder.java:77)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:1038)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query$$Lambda$3.onEvent(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:42)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922)
```

And when I changing the value of field (Status) from firestore no notification is showing.I am changing the data from the field which is under different document ID in firestore.I think their is problem in getting data from firestore.

Screenshots of firestore

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added the screenshots now please give me the solution.

Comment: Are you getting this error la this line `for(DocumentChange documentChange: queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges())`?

Comment: yes I am getting the error in this line as well as  'requests.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {'  in this line

Comment: Have you tried to move all that code in the onCreate to see if it works?

Comment: ok let me see whether it works or not

Comment: Ok, give it a try and tell me if it works

Comment: @AlexMamo same problem is arising..No notification is showing and app crashes when signing out.Help me to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ListenOrder extends Service {

    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    String UID;
    CollectionReference requests;

    public ListenOrder() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        UID = Objects.requireNonNull(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()).getPhoneNumber();
        firebaseFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        requests=firebaseFirestore.collection("Requests").document(UID).collection("RequestStatus");
        requests.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                assert queryDocumentSnapshots != null;
                for(DocumentChange documentChange: queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){
                    switch (documentChange.getType()) {
                        case ADDED:

                            break;
                        case MODIFIED:
                            String OrderID=documentChange.getDocument().getString("OrderID");
                            String doc= documentChange.getDocument().getString("Status");
                            showNotification(OrderID,doc);
                            break;
                        case REMOVED:

                            break;
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void showNotification(String orderid, String status) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel=
                    new NotificationChannel("n","n",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            NotificationManager manager=getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        Intent intent=new Intent(this,order_status_activity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"n");
        builder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.White))
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setContentText("Order was updated "+orderid+" to "+ConvertCodeToStatus(status))
                .setContentTitle("Notification Actions")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_view, "VIEW", contentIntent);
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat= NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        //NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager= (NotificationManagerCompat) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(999,builder.build());
    }

    private String ConvertCodeToStatus(String status) {
        switch (status) {
            case "0":
                return "Placed";
            case "1":
                return "Processed";
            case "2":
                return "Dispatched";
            default:
                return "Delivered";
        }

    }

}
```

This the answer, I just have to create channel Id